# How to hide lacking phpmyadmin warnings?

Tags: phpmyadmin

On a remote ubuntu 18 server when opening data in phpmyadmin from one of the tables, it displays the warnings and popup window(like that https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bxOw.jpg), which is very lacking ...
Is there a way to ignore/hide them?

Server: Localhost via UNIX socket
Server type: MySQL
Server version: 5.7.23-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 - (Ubuntu)
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8)

Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Database client version: libmysql - mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $
PHP extension: mysqliDocumentation curlDocumentation mbstringDocumentation
PHP version: 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

phpMyAdmin  Version information: 4.6.6deb5

Thank!

Comment: It depends on which warnings and popup messages are shown. Perhaps you could copy and paste the messages here.

Comment: I added printscreen in question's text.

Comment: Does this message only occur with one particular table? Which phpMyAdmin, PHP, and MySQL versions do you have (version information for each is available on the main page)?

Comment: I see this error opening ANY table. I provided detailed system information in Content of the topic

Answer (score 25):

The best way to turn off Phpmyadmin errors is to go go config.inc.php and set (or comment out ie removing the // lines in front of the value, which is set to "ask" by default.)

```
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```

Hit save and that's it.

More info https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_SendErrorReports

Answer (score 11):

This is a common error on this phpMyAdmin version.
To solve this open this file

> sudo pico /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/sql.lib.php

Find this line:

> || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr'] == 1)

and replace with:

> || (count($analyzed_sql_results['select_expr']) == 1

Comment: Worked perfectly for 4.6.6deb5 Thanks!

Comment: Working in deb.

Answer (score 0):

PHPMyAdmin version > 4.8

.../phpmyadmin/libraries/config.default.php

```
$cfg['SendErrorReports'] = 'never';
```